# Case assignment does not follow assignment rule

Tags: administration, page-layout, configuration

I have a case record type "Salesforce Queries". I have a page layout "Salesforce Queries | Lite" assigned to this record type. On the page layout settings I didn't select to display the Case Assignment checkbox but I did select "Select by default" setting. When I got a user to create case (submit button clicked) using this record type and page layout the case did not follow the assignment rule but rather stayed in their name. When I then edit the page layout properties and selected the "display Case Assignment checkbox" setting and got the user to create a new case (using the submit button), the case was assigned suing the assignment rule.
Is this a bug?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems consistent with the Knowledge Article at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005470&language=en_US:

> In order to use assignment rules within the user interface, the case
>   assignment checkbox must be set to "show on edit page" within the page
>   layout.